# How to Create a List Within a List with Linq C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a problem, imagine the following situation where I receive the following records from the database:

| idStudent | className | startTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 9 | 11 |
| 4 | Spanish | 9 | 11 |
| 7 | Mathematics | 9 | 11 |
| 7 | Biology | 9 | 11 |
| 7 | Sciences | 9 | 11 |
| 3 | Sciences | 9 | 11 |

Now imagine I have the following class:

```
public class test 
{
    public int idStudent { get; set; }
    public List<StudentGrade> StudentGrades { get; set; }
}

public class StudentGrade
{
    public string className { get; set; }
    public int startTime { get; set; }
    public int endTime { get; set; }
}
```

Using Linq, how would I create this same class where I only have a "test" class with a list of StudentGrades?

I tried to do it like this, but I don't know how to create a list:

```
  var allResult = _getAllClass.FindAll();
  var resul = allResult.GroupBy(x => x.studentID)
                       .Select(s => new test
                        {
                           idStudent = s.Select(ss => ss.studentID).FirstOrDefault(),
                           StudentGrades = /// 
                        }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with `GroupBy`? What LINQ are you using?

Comment: I need to create the list here based on the classes that the student has, these classes are in allResult.

Comment: var allResult = _getAllClass.FindAll();
        var resul = allResult.GroupBy(x => x.studentID)
                           .Select(s => new test
                           {
                               idStudent = s.Select(ss => ss.studentID).FirstOrDefault(),
                               StudentGrades = /// 

                           }

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = allResult.GroupBy(x => x.studentID, (k, g) => new test
            {
                idStudent = k,
                StudentGrades = g.Select(r => new StudentGrade
                {
                    className = r.className,
                    startTime = r.startTime,
                    endTime = r.endTime,
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to process the group to create the `List` inside the `test`var

```
allResult = _getAllClass.FindAll();
var result = allResult.GroupBy(x => x.studentID)
                      .Select(cg => new test {
                          idStudent = cg.Key,
                          StudentGrades = cg.Select(c => new StudentGrade {
                              className = c.className,
                              startTime = c.startTime,
                              endTime = c.endTime,
                           })
                           .ToList()
                       })
                       .ToList();
```